# Can't enable disabled submit with JS Ajax (submit echoed by php)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, disabled-input

I've tried everything:

```
document.getElementById('buy').setAttribute('disabled','false');
document.getElementById('buy').setAttribute('disabled',false);
document.getElementById('buy').removeAttribute('disabled');
document.getElementById('buy').disabled=false;
```

The input submit is has previously been echoed by php:

```
if (empty($basketproductos)) {
echo "<input type='submit' name='buy' value='Buy' disabled='disabled' id='buy'/>";
            }
```

Also tried with disabled='true' instead of disabled='disabled'.

Comment: Make sure the element is added to the DOM before you execute any of those statements.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: You can see an example of that [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/1552587)

Comment: Hmmm but as far as I see that's about how to document.ready, onload, etc, but my js files are loaded after my HTML and anyways the dis-disabling function comes from a lately clicked button...

Comment: I see, in that case, the problem is something else because some of those statements should have enabled the input. Take a look at your browser's console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Any errors... I'm just flushing and regenerating the entire basket in JS as a temporarily solution, if anyone as a new idea...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the button, you should set `true` for `disable` property.

```
document.getElementById('buy').disabled = true;
```

And like @Titus said (on the comment), make sure the element is added to the DOM before you execute a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your js is executed before the html, this should work:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

  var buyButton = document.getElementById('buy');
buyButton.disabled = false; //or true

}, false);
```

or

```
<form action="">
<input type='submit' name='buy' value='Buy' disabled='false' id='buy'/>
  </form>
  <script>    
  var buyButton = document.getElementById('buy');
buyButton.disabled = false; //or true
  </script>
```

Functional example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cfcdh99n/

Comment: Still not working, seems like php isn't just adding the content to the DOM at all.

Comment: @Rajo are you sure empty($basketproductos) is true? try if(true) intead of if(empty($basketproductos))

Comment: Sure :( I think I can let this sink because of the fishy but working solution.

Comment: @Rajo I've added a jsfiddle but maybe the problem is the php

Comment: Thanks it seems to work by itself but it seems like the PHP is doing something weird... Very thankful.